# Как преобразовать строку в массив Python?

Tags: python, строки, list

Столкнулся с проблемой, массив возвращается как:

```
[содержимое1, содержимое2, содержимое3]
```

но это строка, как можно преобразовать это в массив?

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Это можно сделать с помощью list().

Comment: Данная команда не работает с моей проблемой, при вызове команды list на string переменную, она разбивает ее на символы и каждый символ становиться элементом массива

Comment: А мне нужно, чтобы уже готовый массив, но при этом строка, становился массивом

Comment: Возможно это функция split.

Comment: Нет, вот, что у меня есть "[содержимое1, содержимое2, содержимое3]"

Comment: Вот что мне нужно: [содержимое1, содержимое2, содержимое3], а не ["[", "с", "о" и тд

Comment: в вопросе приведен как раз список. А если это строка, то она должна быть в кавычках.

Comment: строка, это итерируемый объект и его можно использовать как for element in string - то есть для большенства реализаций нет необходимости явно преобразовывать str то list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну так, например:

```
lst = eval("[содержимое1, содержимое2, содержимое3]")
```

Но использовать `eval()` нужно очень осторожно и только если вы доверяете источнику, откуда приходит строка.

Answer (score 0):

```
text = '[содержимое1, содержимое2, содержимое3]'    
parse = text.strip('[]').replace(' ', '').split(',') 
print(parse)
```